# How to handle single large request spike to SageMaker endpoint

Tags: amazon-sagemaker, autoscaling, latency

I know SageMaker endpoints have autoscaling as an option, but from my understanding that mainly applies when there is a sustained high request volume. We have the issue that on occasion there will be a huge sudden single spike and then go back to normal. Is autoscaling fast enough (what's the delay?) for it to handle that? Or does it need to actually spin up another instance? Would having two instances at the endpoint help it respond immediately to an isolated request spike? I'm just not clear on what the response delay is for autoscaling, and I have do not see this mentioned in their posts/documentation. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

for your question about time sagemaker need to start new instance is that the time can vary depending on the model size, how long it takes to download the model, and the start-up time of the container.

now what options you have :

1. use hw utilization let say  when reach 76% of cpu scale out
2. another option to use step scale and for example use OverheadLatency
   to scale out

here is a good resource for the above https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/configuring-autoscaling-inference-endpoints-in-amazon-sagemaker/
and  you can always do load testing before you choice the best strategy that fit your need , check this url for load testing
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/load-test-and-optimize-an-amazon-sagemaker-endpoint-using-automatic-scaling/

also , i think using aws sagemaker serverless is good solution for your case but it is in preview stage, right now
https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2021/12/amazon-sagemaker-serverless-inference/

Comment: Be aware with serverless that there are a number of feature exclusions: "Some of the features currently available for SageMaker Real-time Inference are not supported for Serverless Inference, including GPUs, AWS marketplace model packages, private Docker registries, Multi-Model Endpoints, KMS keys, VPC configuration, network isolation, data capture, multiple production variants, Model Monitor, and inference pipelines."